# python: Removing all kinds of quotation marks

Tags: regex, quotation-marks

I have the following string:

```
txt="Daniel's car é à muito esperto"
```

I am trying to remove all kinds of quotation marks.

I tried:

```
txt=re.sub(r"\u0022\u201C\u201D\u0027\u2019\u2018\u2019\u0060\u00B4\'\"", ' ', txt)
```

I expected:

```
"Daniel s car é à muito esperto"
```

but actually nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the regex does not work is that it matches only a single string

```
r"\u0022\u201C\u201D\u0027\u2019\u2018\u2019\u0060\u00B4\'\""
```

To fix that one could use either alteration between each character or a character set.

```
txt=re.sub(r"[\u0022\u201C\u201D\u0027\u2019\u2018\u2019\u0060\u00B4\'\"]", ' ', txt)
```

One might need to pass the `re.UNICODE` flag. Untested.